# rand dependency isn't being recognised even though it has been added to the Cargo.toml dependencies

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, rust-crates

I'm just getting started in rust and I want to use the `rand` dependency, so I added it using `cargo add rand` to the `Cargo.toml` file used by the project.

Here is the code (at the moment a short algorithm to generate a random array of any size):

```
use rand;
const SIZE: usize = 100;
fn main(){
    let array = generate_array();
println!("{:?}", array);
}

fn generate_array() -> [i16; SIZE]{
    let mut array = [0; SIZE];
    let mut i: usize = 0;
    while i < SIZE{
        array[i] = 2;
        i += 1;
    }
    array
}
```

And here is the `Cargo.toml`:

```
[package]
name = "sorting_algorithms"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.5"
```

Every time I try to run the script I get this error message (I'm using VS code):

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `rand`
 --> array_generator.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use rand;
  |     ^^^^ no `rand` in the root

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Comment: How are you compiling the code?

Comment: Running [this script](https://gist.github.com/smarnach/5b4bcfa97bf88a55ec34966e3ed9efc4) works for me. Does it work for you?

Comment: this code doesn't work when I try and run it.

Comment: I'm compiling using the cargo build

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Are you on Windows?

Comment: sorry, by 'doesn't work' I meant that the same error message is appearing; I'm not on windows, I am on MacOs Mojave.

Comment: Please run the script as a `.sh` not copy past the inlined code. Then, perhaps, you'd like to share the output